# AVAssetExportSession - exported video not compatible with camera roll

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have an error and a problem. I want to export a modified video to camera roll, but the exported video is not compatible with camera roll.

I also want to remove the initial recorded video so that I can record more than once, but it generates an error and it doesn't make sense. If I uncomment the code, there will be an error telling me that the final path doesn't exist. I'm assuming that this deletes the initial movie BEFORE the modified version is exported. But I don't understand why that happens since the removal code is BELOW the export code.

Here's the code:

```
    // Create Date Formatter
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss"

    // Create Export Session
    let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exportSession?.videoComposition = videoComposition
    do {
        try exportSession?.outputURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: true).URLByAppendingPathComponent(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())).URLByAppendingPathExtension("mov")
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
    exportSession?.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie
    exportSession?.exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler({
        print("Output File Type: \(exportSession?.outputFileType)")
        print("Output URL: \(exportSession?.outputURL?.absoluteString)")
        print("Video Compatible W/ Camera Roll: \(exportSession?.asset.compatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum)")
        //-----SAVE-----
        if exportSession?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Completed
            {
            print("Export Finished")
            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum((exportSession?.outputURL?.absoluteString)!) //Returns false...
            {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum((exportSession?.outputURL?.absoluteString)!, self, nil, nil)
                print("Video Saved")
                // Show Message
                self.showMessage()
            }
            else
            {
                print("Video Not Saved")
            }
        }
        else if exportSession?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.Failed
        {
            print("Export Error: \(exportSession?.error)")
            print("Export Failed")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Export Cancelled")
        }
    })

    // The code below generates an error
    // Remove Temporary Video
//        do
//        {
//            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtURL(initialOutputURL)
//        }
//        catch
//        {
//            print(error)
//        }
```

So where is the incompatibility from? I want to note that the log shows a QuickTime format and a 720x720 resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I eventually found the answer... which doesn't make much sense either. Maybe it will help others that encounter this problem.

So the code to remove the initial video has to be placed **inside** the `exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler` and not after.

To save the video I just used **ALAssetLibrary**,  `.videoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum` and `.writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum`. I know that it's deprecated, but I want compatibility with iOS 7 too. If you want from iOS 8 and up, use the **PHPhotoLibrary**. This is very weird since both my initial code and the ALAssetLibrary version do the exact same thing. Also, the funny thing is that the log still shows me that the video is not compatible with the camera roll.

The last fix is to use `CGFloat(M_PI_2)` instead of `90` when rotating the video.